# [UINavigationController _hideForKeyboardAppearance]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f9b10eede50

Tags: ios

I am getting this error when trying to open keyboard with "becomeFirstResponder" method of UITextField. Any help much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this link may be help you http://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=it&u=http://www.objectivec.eu/411/uinavigationcontroller-_hideforkeyboardappearance-deallocated&prev=search

Comment: I havn't found anything from this link because nobody replied there :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code. Hope it helps you.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
        [yourtextfieldname resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: resignFirstResponder is for making keyboard hide..I want to show keyboard. that why calling becomeFirstResponder and getting error each time.

Comment: You can use the textField delegate textField should begin editing and use resignFirstResponder there to show keyboard.

Comment: Can you please explain me in more detail. I am not getting your point.

Comment: I have tried your way but still crashing:-                                                                                     - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self registerAndAuthenticateUserWithName:textField.text];
    return YES;
}

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
   {
       [self.registrationTextField resignFirstResponder];
       return YES;
    }

Comment: Is it crashing or what? if crashing then post the crashlog.

Comment: yes crashing on text field tap..the crash log is heading of my question.

Comment: post your whole code in your question. Lemme see once what have you done. @Priyanka

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to share but may be this will be useful for  others in future - 
I was too in this situation
follow these steps - 
1. select your navigation controller in storyboard.
2. just unselect option - Utilities/Attributes Inspector/ Navigation controller/ -
in hide bars/ when keyboard appears.

clean and run .. :)

Happy Coding :D